# Codable - How can I declare optional Array type with empty array

Tags: ios, swift, codable

```
struct Data: Codable {
  let name: String?
  let dataArray: [User] = [User]()
}
```

dataArray is optional so I want to allocate it with empty but my Codable is failing? Can I know How can achieve this, I can declare it as Optional without allocating it. But I want to achieve this.

Comment: there is no meaning to allocate it , why not simply check if it's not nil or use `?? []` where you actually use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift codable, Default Value to Class property when key missing in the JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237085/swift-codable-default-value-to-class-property-when-key-missing-in-the-json)

Comment: I see good answers. But also, `dataArray` is a `let`. You're already assigning it, which can't be changed later.

Answer (score 4):

**You should decode your object manually**:

```
struct Data: Codable {
  let name: String?
  let dataArray: [User]

   enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
              case name
              case dataArray
   }          

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Keys.self)
        name = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        dataArray =  (try? container.decode(User, forKey: . dataArray)) ?? []
    }
}
```

**Or you can create a wrapper** :

```
struct Data: Codable {
  let name: String?
  private let _dataArray: [User]?

  var dataArray : [User] {
      get {
        return   _dataArray ?? []
      }
   }

   enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
                case name
                case dataArray
   }
}
```

Comment: For `dataArray` it should be `decodeIfPresent` with a hard `try`. Because you want default value only iff it's not in JSON. And want to get the error if something else happened, like `dataArray` is there, but type is wrong. Also, `wrapper` options will fail to parse, `dataArray` coding key still refers to Read-Only variable.

Answer (score -1):

Let's suppose it is a User Model:

```
struct User : Codable {
    let userName: String?
}

struct Data: Codable {
   let name: String?
   //Optional Array
   let dataArray: [User]?
}
```

Comment: How will this create an empty array? Did you read the question properly?