# Add default field to Swift Decodable object

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

I have one Swift Codable model like that:

```swift
public struct model: Codable {
    public let id: String
    public let title: String

    public var _tag: MyTag? = MyTag.defaultValue
}
```

The API JSON not contains _tag field.
And I set `_tag` to default value and change/check it later in client side.

I'm pretty sure that field could not be nil. However if remove '?' mark of `public var _tag: Tag?`. Moya JSONDecoder report that error:
`Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound`.

Any workaround to set that field with default value without Optional type and also could decode from JSON without any error?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [With JSONDecoder in Swift 4, can missing keys use a default value instead of having to be optional properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575293/with-jsondecoder-in-swift-4-can-missing-keys-use-a-default-value-instead-of-hav)

Comment: Sure. Thanks  @Robert Dresler