# Swift Firestore custom objects from query while listening for realtime updates with snapshotListener

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I've got issues converting `querySnapshots` that is observed for changes with `snapshotListener` to custom objects.

This is my code but the compiler is complaining:

```
func getCartData(db: Firestore){
        db.collection("test")
        .whereField("Cart", arrayContains: "testItem")
        .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            for doc in documents {
                guard let data = doc.data() else { //here is an error saying: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]'
                  print("Document data was empty.")
                  return
                }

                let result = Result {
                  try doc.data(as: CartDataDocument.self)
                }
                switch result {
                case .success(let userDataDoc):
                    if let userDataDoc = userDataDoc {
                      // A `userDataDoc` value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
                      self.cartData = userDataDoc
                    } else {
                      // A nil value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot,
                      // or the DocumentSnapshot was nil.
                      print("Document does not exist")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    // A `userDataDoc` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
                    print("Error decoding UserDataDocument: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I was able to make custom objects of one Firestore document that got listened to with a `snapshotListener` but had no luck with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems *correct*. If you look at the declaration that Xcode shows while autocompleting, `doc.data()` is indeed a non-nullable `[String: Any]`.

If you want to check if a document is empty you can do it like this:

```swift
guard !doc.data().isEmpty else {
    print("Document data was empty.")
    return
}
```

Otherwise, you could also [override `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575580/925537) in `CartDataDocument` and provide default values for all keys. *This obviously goes in a a different direction: instead of ignoring empty documents, you are adding them to the list with default values. But I've got to ask: why do you have empty documents?*

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I do not have empty documents and do not intend on making empty documents objects if there where any.

Comment: Could it be that Xcode is complaining because ```guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
            }``` is potentially an empty querySnapshot and thus ```documents``` might also be empty?

Comment: If you don't have situations where empty documents may exist, I would just remove this check then. Anyway, the `documents` property is explicitly marked as `non-null` in Objective-C, so `guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents` will unwrap just `querySnapshot`.

Comment: Okey that is good to know how this is done in Objective-C. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome! If this answers your question, make sure to mark it as the approved answer.