# SwiftUI: Replace static data with fetching from json instead (Quiz)

Tags: json, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and trying to build a simple single-player Quiz app. I started by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETb_Wtitg7U&t=1861s) tutorial and then tried to continue on my own. Currently, the questions are hardcoded in my ViewModel but I'd like to change it to fetching from a local JSON file instead. Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Here's a part of my ViewModel with the questions as static data:

```
extension GameManagerVM {
    static var questions = quizData.shuffled()
    static var quizData: [QuizModel] {
        [
            QuizModel(
                      id: 1,
                      question: "Question title 1",
                      category: "Sport",
                      answer: "A",
                      options: [
                          QuizOption(id: 11, optionId: "A", option: "A"),
                          QuizOption(id: 12, optionId: "B", option: "B"),
                          QuizOption(id: 13, optionId: "C", option: "C"),
                          QuizOption(id: 14, optionId: "D", option: "D")
                      ]
            ),

            ...
    }
}
```

Here's a test I did, but I get the error that Xcode can't decode it.
I replace the above code with this:

```
extension GameManagerVM {
    static var questions = quizData.shuffled()
    static var quizData: [QuizModel] = Bundle.main.decode("quizquestions2022.json")
}
```

And here's the JSON.

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "question": "Question title 1",
        "category": "Sport",
        "answer": "A",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "1001",
                "optionId": "A", 
                "option": "A"
            },
            {  
                "id": "1002",
                "optionId": "B", 
                "option": "B"
            },
            {
                "id": "1003",
                "optionId": "C", 
                "option": "C"
            },
            {
                "id": "1004",
                "optionId": "D", 
                "option": "D"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Here are my models

```
struct Quiz {
    var currentQuestionIndex: Int
    var quizModel: QuizModel
    var quizCompleted: Bool = false
    var quizWinningStatus: Bool = false
    var score: Int = 0
}

struct QuizModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var question: String
    var category: String
    var answer: String
    var options: [QuizOption]
}

struct QuizOption: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var optionId: String
    var option: String
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    var isMatched: Bool = false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are decoding, unless you make your own decoding like this [sample init from decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575580/793607) Then all of non-optional the vars or lets in the struct need to be in the json.  Your data doesn't have isSelected or isMatched in the options, so those need to be optional

```
struct QuizOption: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var optionId: String
    var option: String
    var isSelected: Bool?
    var isMatched: Bool?
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you! I added the isSelected and isMatched variables to each option in the JSON file and now it works. But what I don't understand is why it worked with the static data where the options didn't have those variables set?

Comment: Putting in your default values (Bool = false) in there makes it so static data would not need to include isSelected or isMatched.  The decoder doesn't acknowledge those.

Answer (score 0):

to fetch your data from a local JSON file, you could try
this approach, where you need to have a model (`QuizModel`) to
match the json data in your file. Also I used a `class GameManagerVM: ObservableObject`
to hold/publish your data as an example:

```
 import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
 
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var gameManager = GameManagerVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(gameManager.quizData) { quiz in
                Text(quiz.question)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct QuizModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id, question, category, answer: String
    let options: [QuizOption]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, question, category, answer, options
    }
}


struct QuizOption: Codable {
    let id, optionId, option: String
    
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    var isMatched: Bool = false
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, optionId, option
    }
}

class GameManagerVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var questions: [QuizModel] = []
    @Published var quizData: [QuizModel] = []
    
    init() {
       quizData = Bundle.main.decode("quizquestions2022.json")
       questions = quizData.shuffled()
    }

}
```