# Need to map the json to model in Swift

Tags: swift, jsonparser

I have a Json response that i get from a API, the json looks like something like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "63d9d2d57c0cfe791b2b19f6",
            "step": {
                "_id": "step1",
                "status": "STARTED",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "_id": "step2",
                        "status": "NOT_STARTED",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "_id": "step3",
                                "status": "NOT_STARTED",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "_id": "step3",
                                        "status": "NOT_STARTED"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "status": "IN_PROGRESS",
            "createdBy": "2700930039"
        }
    ]
}
```

The json can have multiple levels of children objects inside each other. I need to map this json response to Models in swift

Here are the Models for the Json that i created

```
struct NestedJsonModel:Decodable {
   var data:[LotData]
}

struct LotData:Decodable {
   var _id: String
   var step: StepDetails
   var status: String
   var createdBy: String
}

struct StepDetails:Decodable {
   var _id: String
   var status: String
   var children: [ChildSteps]
}

struct ChildSteps:Decodable {
   var _id: String
   var status: String
   var children: [StepDetails] //because children contains the same model as Step Details
}
```

Here is the decoder code

```
let jsonData = data.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let tableData = try decoder.decode(NestedJsonModel.self, from: jsonData)
    result = tableData.data
    print("****************")
    print(result!)
    print("****************")
}
catch {
    print (error)
}
```

But i keep getting this error

`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "children", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "step", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "children", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "children", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"children\", intValue: nil) (\"children\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: in your struct make ```var children: [ChildSteps]``` optional. eg : ```var children: [ChildSteps]?```. Do same for the ```var children: [StepDetails]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the innermost layer of your JSON does not have a "children" key, but your `ChildSteps` struct does have a non-optional `children` property that needs to be assigned some value.

To fix this, you just need to make `children` have an optional type.

Also note that since `StepDetails` and `ChildSteps` have the same properties, you can merge them too.

```
struct NestedJsonModel:Decodable {
   var data:[LotData]
}

struct LotData:Decodable {
   var _id: String
   var step: StepDetails
   var status: String
   var createdBy: String
}

struct StepDetails:Decodable {
   var _id: String
   var status: String
   var children: [StepDetails]?
}
```

If you don't need to differentiate between "having an empty `children` array" and "not having the `children` key at all", then you can make the `children` property non-optional, and initialise it with an empty array when the key is not found.

This can be conveniently done without handwriting your own custom decoding logic by using a property wrapper as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103704/5133585):

```
@propertyWrapper
struct DefaultEmptyArray<T:Decodable>: Decodable {
    var wrappedValue: [T] = []
    
    init() {}
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        wrappedValue = try container.decode([T].self)
    }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode<T:Decodable>(_ type: DefaultEmptyArray<T>.Type,
                forKey key: Key) throws -> DefaultEmptyArray<T> {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: key) ?? .init()
    }
}

// in StepDetails
@DefaultEmptyArray var children: [StepDetails]?
```